# Eclipse: How can I set Target Platform in config file

Tags: java, eclipse

At first I apologize for my bad English.

Now I use Eclipse 4.5 mars , and added Eclipse 3.6 as Target Platform from IDE. But is there a nice way to set it from config files ??
I want to configure it automatically.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Share...` button on the Target Platform page to create an `xxx.target` file which you can share with other Eclipse installs.

You can also create the target file using 'File > New > Other > Plug-in Development > Target Definition'

Comment: After creating a xxx.target, how can I set it as default ??

Comment: When you open the target editor there is a 'set as target platform' option at the top right of the editor.

Comment: Is it impossible to set from config file?? I want to set it as default from first launching Eclipse. Because plugin(4.5) is automatically selected in run configuration even if i dont want to use 4.5 plugin.

Comment: I don't know of anything to do that.